# Creating Spatialite DB from Swedish OSM

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, ogr, spatialite

I have just started to use GDAL/OGR and I am trying to create a spatialite DB from OSM data. I am using a cut of the Swedish OSM data downloaded from Geofabrik in .osm format. I have used the following command line:

ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" SwedenOSM.sqlite sweden-latest.osm

This created a spatialite db but I also got the following error:
ERROR 1: Too many tags in relation 54224 this is repeated 12 times.

When I try to add the spatialite DB into QGIS 2.6 it doesn't recognise it as a proper DB.

Can some explain to me what is happening and how I go about solving it.

Comment: Your command does not create Spatialite DB but an SQLite + FDO database. You should get good result and faster by using .pbf format and command `ogr2ogr -f SQLite -dsco spatialite=yes SwedenOSM.sqlite sweden-latest.osm.pbf -progress --config OGR_SQLITE_SYNCHRONOUS OFF --config OSM_COMPRESS_NODES YES`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GDAL osm driver makes use of an osmconf.ini file:

http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html

Within that file, you can uncomment the line

```
#other_tags=no
```

to avoid saving all possible names of Sweden in that database column.

By the way, GDAL can read the osm.pbf file directly, no need to extract it first.