# ogr2ogr error converting OSM data

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, spatialite

I am trying to convert from `.osm` to a SQLite database using the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "SQLITE" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES OSM_01.db OSM_01.osm
```

However I am getting an error message `"ERROR 1: String buffer too small"`

Comment: Can you provide a link to the .osm dataset, or give the approximate bounding box of the dataset in which the error will occur?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned at [Creating Spatialite DB from Swedish OSM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128101/creating-spatialite-db-from-swedish-osm), you might consider updating your command as follows:

```
ogr2ogr -f "SQLITE" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES OSM_01.db OSM_01.osm  -progress --config OGR_SQLITE_SYNCHRONOUS OFF --config OSM_COMPRESS_NODES YES
```